# What what software tools do engineers use to programatically generate and parameterize 2D CAD designs

Tags: cad

For many years I've been writing scripts to generate SVG graphics, first in stand-alone python scripts, then in Inkscape extensions, and then in various JS frameworks.

I'm considering creating a web-based analog to the Inkscape extensions framework (with no document inputs, output-only e.g. [this](https://inkscape.org/%7ENeon22/%E2%98%85lasercut-tabbed-box)) so that graphic/industrial designers can create their own adjustable graphical widgets or products and host them online. I'm trying to assess whether or not that would be useful to designers or engineers.

Are there ways in UI-based CAD software to specify e.g. circle B is 1/3 radius of circle A and circle C is 2x the radius of circle B, so that when circle A changes radius, all the circles change size?

I am currently working on a project that is just a single "widget" (see [demo video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbxwfjvz9lfwwjz/2020-12-05%2020-09-48.mkv?dl=0)) and I want to abstract out the parts that could be used to make other widgets.  I'm a programmer and not an engineer so I would really appreciate insights from the discipline.

Comment: Virtually parametric solid model CAD programs allow equation based constraints.

Comment: All the parametric cads can do this. All you realky need is a constraints solver. So not limited to following: Auto Cad, Catia, Creo, Fusion 360, Inventor, NX, Solidedge, Solidworks...

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for OpenSCAD

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I'm aware of OpenSCAD but it's for 3D scripting.

Comment: @EricS thanks, "equation-based constraints" is just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Nothing to stop you using SCAD for 2D applications! What's a cube except a 2D square extruded in a third dimension?

Comment: I found a video which introduces the concept in FreeCAD here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbHS0tvzXFA

Comment: @JonathanRSwift it seems like OpenSCAD doesn't natively support bezier curves: "In general the OpenSCAD SVG import extracts the core geometric information of the objects and transforms that into closed 2D polygons." from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/SVG_Import.  Also, no word on re-exporting SVG there.